# UTF-8 encoding not working in Docker

Tags: docker, utf-8, docker-compose

I'm running a Java program from within a Docker container (started with Docker Compose) and it's throwing a bunch of errors caused by UTF-8 characters (as they can't be mapped to the ASCII charset).  Is there a way to enable UTF-8 encoding from the docker-compose file?

Comment: Seems to me this has nothing to do with docker but all with your Java program.

Comment: The program works outside of the Docker container...inside, it outputs "unmappable character for encoding ASCII" when trying to read a French character

Comment: @JustinBorromeo This proves that you've written your Java program so that it is sensitive to its environment in a way that you don't want it to be. The solution is not to force requirements on the environment but simply to change the program to eliminate its undesired behavior. Please [edit] to show your code.

Comment: @TomBlodget the program is a JUnit test that validates that the code can convert UTF-8 strings to it's simplified ASCII string.  There's no way to avoid dealing with UTF-8.

Comment: The problem is likely when you are using Default rather than UTF-8. There is no such thing as a UTF-8 String or an ASCII String in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check by using below command to set java parameters and then try to run your java program -

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

If it worked using above command, set it using an `ENV` command during docker image build.

Also if you need to set it in bash_profile, refer below portion of Dockerfile -

```
RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_65" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Instead of set using ENV in Dockerfile, you can use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 in docker-compose.yml also under environment: option

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
RUN echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Source: https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/issues/45